# To hold a vampire's beating heart

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

Today, our Toreador Senechal had us deliver the beating heart of a Ravnos to the Nosferatu Duke and Sheriff of the town, well made up in a present basket while the body was kept by the Senechal.

I know that this is a typical feat of Serpentis 5/8 (which makes Setites so dang hard to kill) and might possibly be achieved with flesh forming...

**What *other* Discipline(s) or combinations thereof would allow one to create this fate worse than death** of having the heart removed from the chest and brought to another place **without having the vampire in question meet their final death?**

Comment: My first thought would be Vicissitude, but I haven't found anything linked to that. And AFAIK, ripping someone ELSE's heart out would be Serpentis 8, not 7

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza that's why I had "might possibly be achieved by [fleshforming]" ; though yes, misread the 8 as a 7.

Comment: yeah, I left it as a comment because I couldn't find any evidence corroborating that even Vicissitude could do this at any level below 10 (at this level it is basically a plot device)

Comment: It might be helpful if you clarified exactly what needs to be achieved here. Would it count if the heart was removed but then didn't have any further effect on the vampire (i.e. staking it would not cause paralysis)? Or do you want exactly the same effect as the Serpentis 5 discipline to be applied by some other means?

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme it just needs to be removed and deliverable like the Senechal had ordered - if it can be staked was not tested, but it was unquestionable the very heart that was formerly in the chest of the Ravnos and it most certainly wasn't there anymore.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of how it was done or explanation how it *can* be done?

Comment: @VLAZ how it *can* be done by a vampire without Serpentis. I know it would be trivially for a Mage, but that's out of the question

Comment: Well, not *that* trivial for a mage, either. But I was mainly asking because how it *was* done could have a simple answer and that's a GM fiat. White Wolf aren't above that - there has been artwork (and fluff text, IIRC) describing how somebody brought *the head* of another vampire to the Prince. Well, the beheaded vampire was not still alive (or undead) any more but it's still not something that should be able to happen given that vampires generally fall to dust. However, made for cool artwork. And WW themselves advocate not sticking too close to the rules if you just want something done.

Comment: young vampires turn just into corpses.

Comment: Yes, at Final Death, they just wither away until they get the natural state of decay. However, if so - I don't think presenting the head of a week old vampire to the Prince is a real point of honour. Again, WW are famously for "whatever works best". The books state that the ratio of vampires to mortals is about 1:100 000 yet authors have said that you should have as many vampires as your story needs in your location. If it's a 2 million city and you have 40 vampires there, so be it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a V20 Dark Ages Thaumaturgy ritual that will do this. The larger ritual is for removing the thaumaturge’s own organs, but you can do a limited version on another vampire. This ritual is specific to The Followers of Set like Serpentis, but isn’t part of that discipline and can theoretically be learned by any thaumaturge who can steal the secret.

> Level Five: Cheat The Scale of Hades
>
> “This ritual allows the witch to remove the heart (as well other vital organs) from his body entirely…”
>
> “It is possible to undertake this ritual only partially, stopping with the removal of the heart. Indeed it is possible to perform the ritual upon another Cainite. A vampire is perfectly able to move about without a heart…”
>
> p 311 V20 Dark Ages

Benefit for your target Ravnos:

- Can’t be staked or diablerized through the usual means since the heart isn’t there
- Frenzy rolls difficulty reduced by 2

Drawbacks for your target Ravnos:

- Can be staked or diabelorized remotely
- Any exposure of the heart to sunlight or flame destroys the Ravnos

Comment: In other words: the thaumaturgy ritual is effectively a way to gain the Serpentis 5 effects?

Comment: This aspect of the ritual is almost exactly the same as Heart of Darkness, yes.